# What editor can be used to provide highlighting for Mallard project files?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, documentation, xml

I normally switch between Geany, vim and Emacs (depending on my mood. LOL) when editing on a linux platform.

Recently, I have begun exploring the [Mallard Project](http://projectmallard.org/), but have been unable to find the right tool for editing files to be processed by Mallard.  Does such a tool exist?

**UPDATE**

Shortly after posting my question, I went to the [Mallard mailing list](http://projectmallard.org/mailman/listinfo/mallard-list_projectmallard.org) to search for an answer... and posted my question there.

I share, here, the answer which I received from that list:

> > On Thu, Jan 5, 2012 at 8:44 PM, The Geeko  wrote:
> >
> > ```
> > Is there a tool available which properly handles Mallard documents?
> >
> > I normally use Geany, Emacs and Vim... (depending on my mood and the task at
> > hand), but none of these identify Mallard files; therefore, there is no
> > coloring and other assistance.
> > ```
>
> gedit recognizes Mallard documents, and even has some handy Mallard code snippets.
>
> It does not do code completion like some advanced IDEs, but it does code coloring.
>
> Jim

I appreciated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using Gedit (per Mallard mailing list answer posted in the **update** to my question), another answer was posted (which does not require me to adopt another tool):

> On Thu, 2012-01-05 at 21:44 -0500, The Geeko wrote:
>
> > Is there a tool available which properly handles Mallard documents?
> >
> > I normally use Geany, Emacs and Vim... (depending on my mood and the 
> >     task at hand), but none of these identify Mallard files; therefore, 
> >     there is no coloring and other assistance.
>
> I use nxml-mode in emacs, which does syntax highlighting for any
>   XML file, as well as some other niceties (e.g. C-c C-f closes the
>   current tag). nxml-mode can validate on the fly using RNG schemas.
>
> Jim wrote a tutorial on setting this up here:
>
> http://j1m.net/2010/08/29/duck-duck-gnu-mallard-and-docbook-5-support-in-emacs/
>
> The RNC file you want is here:
>
> http://projectmallard.org/1.0/mallard-1.0.rnc
>
> --
>   Shaun

In the interest of helping others, I share this post as the answer to my original question.

Comment: jedit, excellent java-based editor supports multiple formats.